# why wp_enqueue_scripts() not working?

Tags: wp-enqueue-script

here is code

```
function custom_theme_script(){
    wp_register_style('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.css' );

    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap');

    wp_register_style('style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css');

    wp_enqueue_style('style');

       wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap.min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array(), '3.5.1', true );
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_theme_script');`
```

this is screenshot of head tag
[image]

what is missing in header.php and functions.php file

Comment: That ought to work fine as long as you're calling wp_head. Where did you put your code? Is it definitely being run? Do you not see the scripts in the page? You didn't flag any of your scripts $in_footer=true, but are you calling wp_footer() on your page too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey bro Use this code **get_stylesheet_directory_uri**

```
function custom_theme_script(){
    wp_register_style('bootstrap', get_stylesheet_directory_uri.() .'/css/bootstrap.css' );

    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap');

    wp_register_style('style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css');

    wp_enqueue_style('style');

       wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap.min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array(), '3.5.1', true );
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_theme_script');
```

`